# How to get Options from Select in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: html-select

I needed to quickly be able to tell somebody the options of a select on a form in a non-HTML/human-readable way, using Chrome DevTools on a site not under my purvey.
This happens to be in response to a questioning support department. I'm being told to select an option that isn't there...

Answer (score 0):

...this was a handy quick one liner I thought I'd share because, I am pretty good with JS, but never knew of `console.table` before reading some API usage examples yesterday for an XLSJS library, and it's rad! `Array.from` is needed because x.options is a *HTMLOptionsCollection* (I don't have the rep to create that tag).

Show "*support*" you don't even HAVE that option with this:

`document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(x => console.table(Array.from(x.options)));`

[image: Using console.table to show all select options, robustly]